# How can I query for tasks in a particular project using Rally wsapi for java?

Tags: java, rally, wsapi

I have searched many times but I couldnt find the answer to my problem. Most of the time people write java script code because they are using Rally App SDK. In my case I am developing a desktop application so i am directly using the Webservices using RestApi for java developers. Please help me with this issue.